# How to calculate RAM/memory usage during sqlite queries?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, memory-management, ram

How can I calculate RAM / memory used up during SQL transactions and queries?

I am doing a resource profiling of sqlite and need this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sqlite3_status()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/status.html) and [sqlite3_db_status()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_status.html) functions can return this information.

Answer (score 1):

In windows you can use [perfmon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and monitor CPU/Ram usage for specific process

in other way in [VS2015 we have some new feature in diagnostic tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh704261.aspx) that can help us to monitor CPU/RAM usage in time or event by event
for example if you press any button in your app you can see all details like, memory usage, cpu usage, heaps and etc...